# How to Perform shell script like operation in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I am facing a problem with respect to performing operation like cut, tail, sort, etc. as I was able to do on files in Unix Shell Environment.

I am having a situation like I want the highest time stamp in my file which is not sorted by time stamp and store it in say 'X' and then pass 'X' as argument to my MapReducer Driver Class while executing the MR job.

In Local Mode it is easy to do this :

```
 cut -d, -f <<fieldIndexNo>> <<FileName>> | sort -n | tail -1
```

This gives me the greatest time stamp.

Now In distributed mode, How to go about performing such operations., Or In other Words, what tricks can we use to help solve such problems,

I donot wish to trigger a Mapreduce Job to find the Greatest Time Stamp and then pass it to another Map Reduce Job.

Kindly suggest.
Let me know in case more information is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the files are stored in HDFS and not on the local file system on each node. In that case, you only have 2 options:

- Read all files in your local shell and do the filtering as you did before. Mind you, this is very slow, very inefficient, and completely opposed to the idea of hadoop. But you could do something like:

  `hadoop fs -cat <foldername>/* | cut -d, -f <<fieldIndexNo>> <<FileName>> | sort -n | tail -1`
- Write a Pig job (or spark job or ...) that does it efficiently. It should be a simple max 3 lines script that sorts a file by timestamp and takes the top 1. Then you store this number on HDFS. This will be executed in parallel on each node and will be much quicker than the first solution.